# Python frameworks to write an application with this architecture in azure

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.x, azure-ml

I'm renting an azure vm with 2vcpu with 2gb each (F2s or F2s v2) to implement an application with the following structure:

Db1 (run every 2 hr) --- if trigger (and less than 3 confirmations from this db running) run a saved TensorFlow model -- if model confirms – make request, for 10 hr run script every 2 min and run TensorFlow model every 2 hr

Repeated 26 times (for db2, db3, db4, etc)

the TensorFlow models are not large (100mb each) and each db have 2 different models (the model of one db is not used in other db) and I need to make a complete loop in all the databases (and following processes if trigger and model confirms) in less than 9 min every 2hr it will have maximum total 10 confirmations running simultaneously.

Is there some framework that I can use for this type of task ? I will use a lot of schedules, should I use multi-threading or multiprocessing?

thank you for your enlightenment